# template error message c++

Tags: c++

I have the following header file:

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H


#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "record.h"

using namespace std;

template <class value>
class Database {

  public:

    void write (ostream& out, DBScope scope) const;

    Database <value>() {};
    ~Database();

  private:

    vector <Record<value> > records;

};

#include "database.tem"

#endif
```

database.tem:

```
template <class value>
void Database<value>::write (ostream& out, DBScope scope) const {

 class vector <Record <value> >::iterator itr = records.begin();

 switch (scope) {

    case AllRecords:
      for (; itr != records.end(); itr++) out << itr;
      break;
    case SelectedRecords:
      for (; itr != records.end(); itr++) {
        if (itr.isSelected) out << itr;
      }
      break;

  }
}
```

I was running this header a long with another file and produced this error message, noting that in my header file I have another file called database.tem which is `#include "database.tem"` into my `database.h` file:

```
    database.tem: In member function 'void Database<value>::write (std:: ostream&, DBScope) const [with value = int]':
database.tem: In member function 'void Database<value>::write(std::ostream&, DBScope) const [with value = int]':
interactive.cpp:285:   instantiated from 'bool WriteCommand(Database<value>&) [with value = int]'
interactive.cpp:127:   instantiated from 'bool DispatchCommand(CommandT, Database<value>&) [with value = int]'
interactive.cpp:74:   instantiated from 'void MainLoop(Database<value>&) [with value = int]'
interactive.cpp:99:   instantiated from here
database.tem:6: error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const Record<int>*, std::vector<Record<int>, std::allocator<Record<int> > > >' to non-scalar type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Record<int>*, std::vector<Record<int>, std::allocator<Record<int> > > >' requested
interactive.cpp:285:   instantiated from 'bool WriteCommand(Database<value>&) [with value = int]'
interactive.cpp:127:   instantiated from 'bool DispatchCommand(CommandT, Database<value>&) [with value = int]'
interactive.cpp:74:   instantiated from 'void MainLoop(Database<value>&) [with value = int]'
interactive.cpp:99:   instantiated from here
database.tem:11: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'out << itr'
```

I have no idea what this messsage is talking about, can someone help me

Comment: It would help if you'd put the full error message, and the piece of code on which you get it...

Comment: Please, post database.tem file and #include sentences in database.h. Let's see whats happening.

Comment: @littleadv the error is around 100 lines long, and the code is even more, I'll add some of the code and see if it helps I don't want to copy/paste the whole thing

Comment: @SNpn: please put at least the lines following the error lines you posted

Comment: @SNpn - most of these lines are the templates. Somewhere inside that text the actual error message is buried. Find it, and bring it here. You don't expect us to just guess it, do you ?

Comment: @jcalvosa the `read` function is whats inside `database.tem`

Comment: I doubt the SO is a good tool for real-time collaborative debugging. You either provide complete question, with code complete to allow to understand it as well as complete error message or your question is plain invalid.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper I've edited my original post with extra lines of the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error has to do that the method is const, hence `records` is const, and `reconds.begin()` returns a `const_iterator`.

```
template <class value>
void Database<value>::write (ostream& out, DBScope scope) const {

 vector <Record <value> >::const_iterator itr = records.begin();
```

The second error means that you probably meant to dereference the iterator:

```
for (; itr != records.end(); itr++) out << *itr;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have only posted a partial error message but the error is probably that you  need to write itr->isSelected rather than itr.isSelected.

Also it's preferable to use ++itr instead of itr++ when using iterators.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to print is iterator object, not the value it refer to:

```
out << itr;
```

Replace that with

```
out << *itr;
```

Also make sure that class Record has either method or function defined:

```
ostream& out operator <<(ostream& out); // method

ostream& out operator <<(ostream& out, const Record &); //function
```

Comment: i've tried that and it still gives me that `error: conversion from '___gnu` etc error